# When can non-English be used on this site?

Tags: discussion, chat, language

Suppose a number of users from Russia, for example, decided to create a room discussing Russian physics and physicists, and they decided to converse in the Russian language. This would unintentionally exclude most people from here participating and learning from the conversation.

What are the guide lines, if any, on where non-English can be used on this site?

Comment: +1 because there are such rooms in existence. E.g. [This](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4092/chat-moderation)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In general, we don't care what happens in chat rooms associated with the site, so if some users want to set up a chat room for discussion in a foreign language, that [should be okay](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92996). However, if chat moderators have reason to suspect that the foreign language is being used to disguise communication that would otherwise be unacceptable (e.g. insults), they'll have to deal with that, and shutting down the chat room is one of the possible consequences (in extreme cases).

On the main site, meta site, and in the [main site chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar), all content should be in English. (Or more precisely, all content should be understandable to English speakers.)

Comment: If you don't speak english then (a) this comment will be of no use to you and (b) try speaking in equations; as physicists we can usually understand equation speak.